# Why does the function fail after UrlFetchApp.fetchAll () is executed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, urlfetch

After executing the useFetchAll function, I pass the response value to the stringform function, and I get an error

> TypeError: A.forEach is not a function

In the example, I made the variable asdf and copied the Logger.log (response) value into it, the stringform function works and returns an array. Why does the function throw an error when the value is (response)?

```
    // Using UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()
    function useFetchAll(req) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(req);
     
    var asdf=[[["a",1],["a",2],["a",3],["a",4],["a",5]], [["b",6],["b",7],["b",8],["b",9],["b",10]], [["c",11],["c",12],["c",13],["c",14],["c",15]], [["d",16],["d",17],["d",18],["d",19],["d",20]], [["e",21],["e",22],["e",23],["e",24],["e",25]]];
     
    Logger.log(response);
    Logger.log(stringform(asdf));
     
    }
     
    
   function stringform(asdf) {
    let formad = '';
      asdf.forEach(A => {
        A.forEach(r => {
          formad += r.join(',') + '%0A';
        });
      });
      return formad;
      
    }
```

Comment: What was the error code?

Comment: TypeError: A.forEach is not a function

Comment: Ah then A was probably not an array

Comment: In your case the A here `asdf.forEach(A => {` is still an array of arrays because you have a 3 dimension array of arrays.  So you need to flatten it out a little more

Comment: `A` can't be a array. It's probably a string. You need to `JSON.parse(A)` it to get the  underlying array.

Comment: asdf was not defined in the lower function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question of `Why does the function fail after UrlFetchApp.fetchAll () is executed?`, from your script and `In the example, I made the variable asdf and copied the Logger.log (response) value into it, the stringform function works and returns an array. Why does the function throw an error when the value is (response)?`, I thought that the reason of your issue is due to that `fetchAll` returns `HTTPResponse[]` which is an array.

For example, when one of requests `req` returns 2 dimensional array like `[["a",1],["a",2],["a",3],["a",4],["a",5]]`, `Logger.log(response)` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(req)` shows `[[["a",1],["a",2],["a",3]], [["a",1],["a",2],["a",3]]]`. In your situation, I thought that the values from the muliple requests might be included in `response`.

If my understanding of your situation is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function useFetchAll(req) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(req);
  var asdf = response.map(r => JSON.parse(r.getContentText()));
  Logger.log(stringform(asdf));
}

function stringform(asdf) {
  let formad = '';
  asdf.forEach(A => {
    A.forEach(r => {
      formad += r.join(',') + '%0A';
    });
  });
  return formad;
}
```

or,

```js
function useFetchAll(req) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(req);
  var values = response.reduce((t, r) => t += JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).map(c => c.join(',') + '%0A'), "");
  Logger.log(values)
}
```

#### Reference:

- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

  > Return: HTTPResponse[] — An array of HTTP response data from each input request.

Answer (score 2):

#### It's an array that's 3 deep.

```
function myfunction() {
  let s = '';
  var asdf = [[["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["a", 3], ["a", 4], ["a", 5]], [["b", 6], ["b", 7], ["b", 8], ["b", 9], ["b", 10]], [["c", 11], ["c", 12], ["c", 13], ["c", 14], ["c", 15]], [["d", 16], ["d", 17], ["d", 18], ["d", 19], ["d", 20]], [["e", 21], ["e", 22], ["e", 23], ["e", 24], ["e", 25]]];
  asdf.forEach(A => {
    A.forEach(r => {
      s += r.join(',')+ '\n';
    })
  })
  Logger.log(s);
}

Execution log
3:53:29 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:53:29 PM  Info    a,1
a,2
a,3
a,4
a,5
b,6
b,7
b,8
b,9
b,10
c,11
c,12
c,13
c,14
c,15
d,16
d,17
d,18
d,19
d,20
e,21
e,22
e,23
e,24
e,25
3:53:30 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

You lower function would have worked but asdf was not defined in that function.

Your lower function runs like this:

```
function stringform(asdf) {
  var asdf = [[["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["a", 3], ["a", 4], ["a", 5]], [["b", 6], ["b", 7], ["b", 8], ["b", 9], ["b", 10]], [["c", 11], ["c", 12], ["c", 13], ["c", 14], ["c", 15]], [["d", 16], ["d", 17], ["d", 18], ["d", 19], ["d", 20]], [["e", 21], ["e", 22], ["e", 23], ["e", 24], ["e", 25]]];
    let formad = '';
      asdf.forEach(A => {
        A.forEach(r => {
          formad += r.join(',') + '\n';
        });
      });
      Logger.log(formad)
      
    }
```